# DateTime.TryParse different results

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-parsing

As part of my unittests for an application I check a few datetime strings for their ability to get parsed. I recently noticed that on one machine the string `"0-02-20 11:36"` can get parsed to `{2000-02-20 11:36:00}` by `DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out parsedTimeStamp)` while on other machines it can't.

```cs
string dt = "0-02-20 11:36";
DateTime parsedTimeStamp;
DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out parsedTimeStamp);
Console.WriteLine(parsedTimeStamp);
```

Comment: And the culture on that particular machine was...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing a `DateTime`, like all parsing in the framework, is **culture dependent**.

I would assume that on the exceptional machine, the culture settings use a `yyyy-MM-dd` format, while on the other machines, the date format was `MM-dd-yyyy`.

To work around this, you can parse in a specific culture or using an invariant culture.

```
DateTime.TryParse(dateString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedTimeStamp);
```

---

It turns out there are quite a few of these cultures:

```
foreach (var c in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures))
{
    if (c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern == "yyyy-MM-dd")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", c.DisplayName, c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
    }
}
```

---

```
Korean: yyyy-MM-dd  
Polish: yyyy-MM-dd  
Albanian: yyyy-MM-dd  
Swedish: yyyy-MM-dd  
Khmer: yyyy-MM-dd  
Sinhala: yyyy-MM-dd  
Korean (Korea): yyyy-MM-dd  
Polish (Poland): yyyy-MM-dd  
Albanian (Albania): yyyy-MM-dd  
Swedish (Sweden): yyyy-MM-dd  
Khmer (Cambodia): yyyy-MM-dd  
Sinhala (Sri Lanka): yyyy-MM-dd  
Sami, Northern (Sweden): yyyy-MM-dd  
French (Canada): yyyy-MM-dd  
Sami, Lule (Sweden): yyyy-MM-dd  
Sami, Southern (Sweden): yyyy-MM-dd  
Sami (Southern): yyyy-MM-dd  
Sami (Lule): yyyy-MM-dd
```