# When is empty string "" a valid DateTime string format?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

Seeing a strange issue where on some systems the below code steps into the if statement (i.e. it returns true) while in other systems it returns false and steps into the else statement. What environmental conditions or framework version changes am I missing where this was changed? For example .net Fiddle returns true, but my own console apps return false.

```
    DateTime time;
    formatText = "";
    if (DateTime.TryParse (DateTime.Now.ToString(formatText), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out time))
    {
        // If TryParseExact Worked
        Console.WriteLine ("True: " + time.ToString ()); 
    }
    else
    {
        // If TryParseExact Failed
        Console.WriteLine ("Failed to Parse Date");
    }
```

Comment: "If format is `null` or an empty string, the general format specifier, 'G', is used." The `G` format of the current culture need not match any format accepted by the invariant culture. Specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the `.ToString` as well if you want consistent results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime.TryParse different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650839/datetime-tryparse-different-results)

Comment: "`// If TryParseExact Worked`" but it's not `TryParseExact`, it's `TryParse`...

Comment: And if you want to know on which cultures exactly it fails - loop through `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)` and execute your code for each of them with `DateTime.Now.ToString(formatText, culture)`.

Comment: [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/adhUBN) that shows the cultures toString output for `G` along with if they pass your test.

Comment: @Lithium that is an extremely helpful script to explain it to my colleagues who brought it to me for help, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String representations of `DateTime` are culture specific.

Passing an empty string or `null` as the `format` parameter of the `ToString` overload of `DateTime` is the same as passing the [standard format specifier `"G"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-general-date-long-time-g-format-specifier) - from the remarks section of the [DateTime.ToString Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) msdn page:

> If format is null or an empty string, the general format specifier, 'G', is used.

The `TryParse` overload you are using attempts to parse the `DateTime` value using the date and time formats available in the `IFormatProvider` format parameter - `InvariantCulture` in your case - so when you use `TryParse` with `InvariantCulture`, unless your current culture's `ShortDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern` properties are the same as in `InvariantCulture`, the `tryParse` will fail.